# CALL with CURL an API through Python

Tags: python, curl

I am working with an API for license plate recognition ; and i get this curl command :

How to implement such call with curl in PYTHON?

```
curl "https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/async/recognizelicenseplates/v1?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.havenondemand.com%2Fsample-content%2Fvideos%2Fgb-plates.mp4&source_location=GB&apikey=695e513c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"

curl -X POST --form "url=https://www.havenondemand.com/sample-content/videos/gb-plates.mp4" --form "source_location=GB" --form "apikey=695e513c-xxxx-xxxx-a666-xxxxxxxxxx" https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/async/recognizelicenseplates/v1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, using the `requests` module is a much better option. Install it first:

```
pip install requests
```

Then do this:

```
import requests

API_URL = "https://api.havenondemand.com/1/api/async/recognizelicenseplates/v1"

data = {
    "url": "https://www.havenondemand.com/sample-content/videos/gb-plates.mp4",
    "source_location": "GB",
    "apikey": "695e513c-xxxx-xxxx-a666-xxxxxxxxxx"
 }

response = requests.post(API_URL, data)
print(response.json())
```

Basically, any form fields should go inside the `data` dictionary as key value pairs. We use `requests.post()` function here. The function takes the target URL as the first parameter. And the form values as the second parameter.

We get a response object back. You can see the raw response by printing out the value of `response.content`. However, if you know that the response is JSON, you can use the `json()` method to parse the response and get back Python data type (dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. You could start with [urllib2](https://github.com/HPE-Haven-OnDemand/havenondemand-python) (or any other HTTP library like requests). A better option could be to directly use the python client library for [havenondemand](https://github.com/HPE-Haven-OnDemand/havenondemand-python)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to call Haven OnDemand APIs is to use HPE official libraries. You can install the HOD Python lib and use it as follows:

## install the lib

pip install havenondemand

```
# put these in your file
from havenondemand.hodclient import *
from havenondemand.hodresponseparser import *

client = HODClient("API_KEY", version="v1")
parser = HODResponseParser()

# callback function
def asyncRequestCompleted(response):
    jobID = parser.parse_jobid(response)
    if jobID is None:
        errorObj = hodParser.get_last_error()
        for err in errorObj.errors:
            print ("Error code: %d \nReason: %s \nDetails: %s\n" % (err.error,err.reason, err.detail))
    else:
        client.get_job_status(jobID, requestCompleted)

def requestCompleted(response):
    payloadObj = parser.parse_payload(response)
    resp = ""
    if payloadObj is None:
        errorObj = parser.get_last_error()
        for err in errorObj.errors:
            if err.error == ErrorCode.QUEUED:
                time.sleep(2)
                client.get_job_status(err.jobID, requestCompleted)
                return
            elif err.error == ErrorCode.IN_PROGRESS:
                time.sleep(10)
                client.get_job_status(err.jobID, requestCompleted)
                return
            else:
                resp += "Error code: %d \nReason: %s \nDetails: %s\n" % (err.error,err.reason)
    else:
        print(payloadObj)

params = {}
params['url'] = 'https://www.havenondemand.com/sample-content/videos/gb-plates.mp4'
params['source_location'] = 'GB'
hodApp = HODApps.RECOGNIZE_LICENSE_PLATE
client.post_request(params, hodApp, True, callback=asyncRequestCompleted)
```